# Plotting two pandas data frame columns against each other

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data frame like this:

```
timestamp                  vote_count
00:12:30                   350 
05:05:00                   50 
01:10:35                   200 
05:05:00                   175 
..............................
..............................
00:12:30                   900
```

Now I want to visualize the vote_count for the timestamps and do some analysis on that further. How can I plot the two columns against each other using matplotlib or seaborn?

**Note**: The timestamp is in 24hr format. Also, at any timestamp, there can be multiple vote counts.

Comment: `df=df.groupby('timestamp').sum()` followed by `df.plot(x='timestamp', y='vote_count')`

Comment: The provided documentation of both libraries should be more than enough for you to figure this out.

Comment: @Emre why don't you upgrade your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to groupby to deal with multiple vote counts:

> df.groupby('timestamp').sum().plot(x='timestamp', y='vote_count')